# How to replace with second column with missing if 0?

Tags: pandas

I have a csv file which is below

```
ID,Name1,Name2
1,A,A
2,B,B
3,C,D
4,0,F
5,0,Z
```

The new table is below

```
ID,NewName
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,F
5,Z
```

Basically if `0` coming in the `Name1` has to replace with `Name2`

Comment: Use `df['NewName'] = np.where(df['Name1'].eq('0'), df['Name2'], df['Name1'])`

Comment: Or `df['NewName'] = np.where(df['Name1'].eq(0), df['Name2'], df['Name1'])`

Comment: Assuming 0 is string, here is a thought `df[['Name1', 'Name2']].max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `replace` then do `bfill`

```
df['Name']=df.drop('ID',1).replace({'0':np.nan}).bfill(1).iloc[:,0]
df
   ID Name1 Name2 Name
0   1     A     A    A
1   2     B     B    B
2   3     C     D    C
3   4     0     F    F
4   5     0     Z    Z
```

Comment: can you explain Master, instead of bfill(1), can i give bfill('Name1'), or how to give the column name?

Comment: @Nons this is mark the 0 as nan in all Names , then we do the bfill, fill from backward, then we just need take the 1st column, we can find the target, since all the NaN value fill by the not null value from nest column, if all the row is 0 you will received NaN at the end. Notice this method is unlimited for how many Names you have , if you have more than 2 like Name1, Name2, Name3 , this method still works

Comment: @Nons bfill(1) is bfill(axis=1), if you only have two columns you can always do df.Name1.replace({'0':np.nan}).fillna(df.Name2) to assign